# Adding value of every item in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to add every value under "title" from a dictionary to a list but i always get KeyError: 'title'.

```
list = []
q = input("Search:")



search = SearchVideos(q, mode = 'dict')
dictt = (search.result())
print(dictt)

for i in dictt:
    list.append(dictt['title'])
```

Comment: You should check the content of `dictt` firstly.

Comment: what is the reason of the `(....)` in `dictt = (search.result())`

Comment: you `print(dictt)` and you don't look at the output to see what might be wrong and expect us to know what is in `dictt`

Comment: {'search_result': [{'index': 0, 'id': 'CLXt3yh2g0s', 'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLXt3yh2g0s', 'title': "Example - 'Changed The Way You Kiss Me' (Official Video)", 'channel': 'Data Records', 'duration': '3:15', 'views': 103728437, 'thumbnails': ['https://img.youtube.com/vi/CLXt3yh2g0s/default.jpg', 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/CLXt3yh2g0s/hqdefault.jpg', 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/CLXt3yh2g0s/mqdefault.jpg', 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/CLXt3yh2g0s/sddefault.jpg', 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/CLXt3yh2g0s/maxresdefault.jpg'], 'channelId': 'UCnW6K9iOXQ6VJVisrlnQ3VA'}. It prints this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few problems here. 
First, you're not accessing the right value. It looks like dictt has only one key: `search_result` and you should iterate on it's value.
In addition, `list.append(value)` will not add the value to a list. you need to make a list and then do `new_list.append(value)`. 
lastly you didn't use `i` in your loop.

It should look like this:

```
new_list = []
for item in dictt['search_result']:
    new_list.append(item['title'])
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. it's my first time using dictionaries and i'm a bit confused.